Gradle cannot recognize "minSdk MSBUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION" when building APK with AGDE
We encounter a build error because Gradle could not recognize "minSdk MSBUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION" from build.gradle. The error no longer occurs if we change it to "minSdkVersion MSBUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION". My best guess is that AGDE finds and parses "minSdkVersion" but not "minSdk"
Our build config:

Android Gradle Plugin 8.7.0
Gradle 8.10.1
Android Game Development Extension 2022-v23.2.91
Visual Studio 2022

